# My webcam is not showing using Tkinter in a while loop

Tags: python, tkinter, webcam, mediapipe

i have this problem where my webcam is not showing using Tkinter,i want to make a GUI where the person click the webcam button and start detecting sign languague, works only when the function "mostrarWebcam" is in the while loop, but in that condition, the webcam dont show up. I hope you can help me whit this issue.

```
def mostrarWebcam():
    global cap
    sequence = []
    sentence = []
    predictions = []
    threshold = 0.5

    while cap is not None:

        ret,frame = cap.read()
        if ret == True:
            frame=imutils.resize(frame,width=700,height=1200)
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)

            frame,results = mediapipe_detection(frame,holistic)
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            draw_styled_landmarks(frame,results)

            keypoints = extract_keypoints(results)
            sequence.append(keypoints)
            sequence = sequence[-50:]

            if len(sequence) == 50:
                res = modelo_cargado.predict(np.expand_dims(sequence, axis=0))[0]
                print(actions[np.argmax(res)])
                predictions.append(np.argmax(res))
            
            
        #3. Viz logic
                if np.unique(predictions[-10:])[0]==np.argmax(res): 
                    if res[np.argmax(res)] > threshold: 
                    
                        if len(sentence) > 0: 
                            if actions[np.argmax(res)] != sentence[-1]:
                                sentence.append(actions[np.argmax(res)])
                        else:
                            sentence.append(actions[np.argmax(res)])

                if len(sentence) > 5: 
                    sentence = sentence[-5:]

            # Viz probabilities
                frame = prob_viz(res, actions, frame, colors)

            frame = cv2.rectangle(frame, (0,0), (640, 40), (245, 117, 16), -1)
            framex = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            im   = Image.fromarray(framex)
            img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = im)

            lblVid.configure(image=img)
            lblVid.image = img
                    
            lblVid.after(10, mostrarWebcam)
        else:
            lblVid.image=""
            cap.release()
```

Comment: This probably IS working.  The problem is you are in an infinite loop here (`while cap is not None:`), so this routine never exits.  You never get back to Tkinter's main loop, so it is unable to update the screen.  Since you're using `after`, just delete the `while` loop.   Let it display the frame and return.

Comment: There's another issue.  Because of a design flaw in Tkinter, the `configure` call doesn't keep a reference to the image.  When the function exits, the image is deleted and the label goes blank.  You'll need to store that in a global somewhere.

Comment: Thanks¡ , i define sequence as a global and it works.